# Can't see Balance in 401k account

Tags: united-states, 401k, contribution

I put about $400 into a 401k account, but the balance still says $0. Likewise, the vested balance is also $0. Why is this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you need to call HR or payroll or customer service.

Comment: I think this is a valid question that others may have,. I suggest we don't close it.

Comment: I don't know enough about the mechanics of a 401k to know for sure (hence am reluctant to vote to reopen), but I suspect it _could_ be a valid question useful to others, if – for example – there's a period of a few days or so between money hitting a 401k and showing as invested, perhaps due to T+2 settlement. (Something _beyond_ the normal processing time of a check/ACH payment).

Answer (score 2):

If this is a very recent deposit give it a few days.

For me I was paid on Friday the 14th because the 15th is a weekend day. So the pay stub noted that there was a 401K contribution from me, and the expected match amount from the company. Yet on Saturday morning it wasn't reflected in the 401K account. With Monday being a federal holiday I don't expect to see it until Tuesday.

Otherwise contact HR.